# How to add class to anchor $(this).closest('ul').children('li')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning traversal with jquery, I don't understand how it's adding the class to all the items in the unordered list, I know its something simple. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
    $('li').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);

        if($(this).closest('ul').children('li').hasClass('active')) {
              $(this).closest('ul').children('li').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('ul').children('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">Subjects
          <li><a href="#">200</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">215</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">221</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">220</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">250</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">220</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">100</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">101</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand how it's adding the class to all the items in the unordered list,

You just need to remove the class first and then add to current element.

```js
$(function() {
    $('li').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');         
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">Subjects
          <li><a href="#">200</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">215</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">221</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">220</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">250</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">220</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">100</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">101</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just as a small addition, how could I also get the id

Comment: @TheBrokenSpanner `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: Just tried if($(this).attr("id") === '5') alert("working"); and it didn't work

Comment: First of all the main problem wasn't about that you have written and secondly @TheBrokenSpanner - the `li` elements doesn't have `id` attribute.

Comment: @TheBrokenSpanner Make sure you have given Id's.

Comment: Ok sorry I will ask a separate question, I had added id's to all elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to put "active" class only on the current clicked element. Then update your jQuery code part as below.

```
<script>
   $(function() {
      $('li').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).closest('ul').children('li').hasClass('active')) {
           $(this).closest('ul').children('li').removeClass('active');
        }
        $(this).addClass('active');
     });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: This helped me tackling with active on list items while i was clicking the anchor within the list. Going back to the parent of the LI element and then removing them did for me the track

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).closest('ul').children('li')` affects every `li` element.
Assuming that you want to mark only the clicked `li` elements, here's the solution:

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">Subjects
        <li><a href="#">200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">215</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">221</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">250</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">101</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it could certainly be simplified if that's what you are looking for? If not leave a comment and I will edit :)

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".nav-pills li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">Subjects
        <li><a href="#">200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">215</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">221</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">250</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">101</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if this is what you want, but there is a simple code just manage `active` class `toggle`  in elements.

```js
$(function() {
  //    $('li').click(function(e) {
  //        e.preventDefault();
  //        var $this = $(this);
  //
  //        //if($(this).closest('ul').children('li').hasClass('active')) {
  //              //$(this).closest('ul').children('li').removeClass('active');
  //        } else {
  //            //$(this).closest('ul').children('li').addClass('active');
  //        }
  //    });

  $('.nav-stacked li').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav-stacked li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">Subjects
        <li><a href="#">200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">215</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">221</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">250</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">101</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```